# Sharepoint Current user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I am using following code in masterpage to print current user

```
welcome, <%= Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name%>
```

My output is as follows

```
welcome, Smith, Rick
```

where last name=Smith and first name=Rick

but I need as follows

```
welcome, Rick Smith
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in server tags:

```
<%= Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name.Contains(" ") ? string.Format("{0} {1}", Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name.Split(' ')[1], Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name.Split(' ')[0]) : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name %>
```

It seems kind of big but should do the job :)